# Which tense should I use in "Roger told me that you { have / had } a pen"?

Tags: tense

Should I say:

> Roger told me that you **have** a pen.

OR

> Roger told me that you **had** a pen.

Assume I talked to Roger a few hours ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either could be correct. It depends on what you're talking about.

If you're talking about present possession you use present tense:

> Hey, Shannon, Roger told me you have one of those new pens that shoots death rays. Could I take a look at it? I'm thinking of getting one.

If you're talking about past possession you use past tense:

> Hey, Shannon, Roger told me last spring that you had a death-ray pen that wasn't working. Did you manage to get it fixed, or did you throw it away? I've found a guy who knows how to fix them.

Comment: Discounting those who were simply admitting to having lied, I imagine probably more than half the people who've ever said ["I told him my name was XXXX"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+told+him+my+name+was%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) were *still* called XXXX at time of speaking/writing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Indeed. I'd accept either *had* or *have* in the first example (present possession) but I do agree that *had* is required in the second example. (Also, death-ray pens? Where can I get one of those? ;))